# Sensitive data in process substitution

Tags: permissions, security, encryption, process-substitution

Let's say I do:

```
#!/bin/bash
content="foo"
pass="secret-password"
echo $content | ccrypt -f -k <(echo -n $pass)
```

Can the permission set on the process substition `/dev/fd/*` files be trusted to keep the passphrase safe for the duration of `ccrypt`?

Comment: You're passing it as the first argument of your script, so it will show in the output of `ps` (for any user) anyway!

Comment: Seeing your edit, the problem is with `pass=$1`, if you call your script as `the-script secret-password`, then anyone running `ps -ef` will see `the-script secret-password`.

Comment: Geez, O.P. presumably added those additional commands just for demonstration purposes. The question is clearly about the security of using process substitution, and not about passing a password as script argument. Asking for the security of process substitution for me implies that the asker knows that passing password as argument is insecure...

Answer (score 10):

Let's break it down:

```
content=$(cat -)
```

That's the same as `content=$(cat)`. That's using *command substitution* which in `bash` uses a pipe. At one end of the pipe, `cat` is writing what it reads from its stdin. And `bash` at the other end is reading that to store into `$content`.

However, before doing that, it strips trailing newline characters and also would choke on NUL characters. To be able to store arbitrary data in a variable, you can't use `bash`; you'd need to use `zsh` instead and do something like:

```
content=$(cat; echo .); content=${content%.}
```

to work around the newline stripping issue.

Note that the data to be stored in `$content` is fed through the stdin of your script. That would be available (on Linux) as `/proc/pid-of-your-script/fd/0` which is the same as `/proc/pid-of-cat/fd/0`. And since `cat` copies it to a pipe to `bash`, it's also in `/proc/pid-of-cat/fd/1` and `/proc/pid-of-script/fd/fd-to-the-other-end-of-the-pipe`.

In any case here, you're using the content of `$content` only once so it doesn't make sense to do that intermediate step.

---

```
pass=$1
```

Here, you're saying that the very secret *key* is taken from the first argument of the script.

You cannot pass secret data as a command line arguments. Command line arguments are not secret. They show in the output of `ps -efwww`. On Linux, `/proc/pid/cmdline` which contains them is world-readable (by default; on Linux, access to `/proc/pid` can be administratively restricted to processes with the same euid though that's rarely done as that affects the behaviour or `ps` among other things).

On some systems, they may even be logged via some process accounting/auditing mechanism.

---

`echo $content` is wrong for several reasons:

- `echo` cannot be used for arbitrary data. It doesn't work properly with arguments like `-n`, `-neneneene`... and depending on the environment things that contain backslashes.
- An unquoted `$content` means invoking the split+glob operator which you do not want and would cause problems if `$content` contains characters of `$IFS` or wildcards.
- it adds an extra newline character.

You'd want:

```
printf %s "$content"
```

And make sure  trailing newlines have not been stripped earlier.

As that `printf` is part of a pipeline, it will be run in a child process whose stdout will be a pipe. On Linux, `/proc/pid-of-that-child-process/fd/1` will give access to that content. So will `/proc/pid-of-ccript/0`.

---

In

```
ccrypt -f -k <(echo -n $pass)
```

There's again the problem of `echo` and the unquoted `$pass`.

`echo` (again running in a child process) will write the password to a pipe. The other end of the pipe will be made available on fd *n* to `ccrypt` and `<(...)` will expand to something like `/dev/fd/n` or `/proc/self/fd/n`. `ccrypt` will open that file (so on a new fd), which again (on Linux) will be available as `/proc/pid-of-ccrypt/fd/that-fd` in addition to `/proc/pid-of-ccrypt/fd/n` and `/proc/pid-of-echo/fd/1`

---

Now, the major problem in your code is not process substitution or any of those other pipes, but the fact that the password is given as a command line argument of a command (here, your script).

Process substitution involves a normal pipe, just as with `$(...)` command substitution and `|`. `/dev/fd/x` on most systems except Linux is only meaningful to the corresponding process, so cannot leak to other processes. But other processes running as the same euid (or as root) could read the memory of those processes anyway (like debuggers do) and recover that password (or probably get it from the same source anyway).

On Linux, `/dev/fd` is a symlink to `/proc/self/fd` and `/proc/self` a dynamic symlink to `/proc/the-pid`. `/proc/pid/fd` is by default readable by processes with the same  euid (though there can be further restrictions added, the same ones that restrict who may attach a debugger to a process).

For fds that point to pipes, `/proc/pid/fd/that-fd` acts like a named pipe. So another process (again running as the same euid or root) could steal the content of the pipe. But in any case, if they can do that, they can also directly read the content of the processes memory so there's no point trying to guard against that.

---

Instead of passing the password on a command line, you could pass it via an environment variable. The environment is a lot more private than the argument list. On Linux, `/proc/pid/environ` is only readable by processes with the same euid (or `root`).

So your script could just be:

```
#! /bin/sh -
exec ccrypt -f -E PASSWORD
```

And call it as

```
PASSWORD=secret-phrase the-script < data-to-encrypt
```

Comment: Valuable answer, which does not only point out and dissect the pitfalls in the sample script, but actually answers the original question in great depth. This is a great example why writing secure code is hard.