# encrypt private keys for dropbear ssh-access

Tags: ssh, security, encryption, key-authentication, dropbear

I'd like to use [`dropbear`](https://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear.html) as an alternative, minimal ssh-server and -client.  `dropbear` allows the use of private-public-keys for ssh-access, although [the keys are not identical to the ones used by `openssh` and have to be converted using the `dropbearconvert`-command](https://github.com/mkj/dropbear) (which is easy to do).

The issue I'm having is that [`dropbear` doesn't natively support encrypted private keys](https://github.com/mkj/dropbear).  But leaving unencrypted ssh-keys on my laptop is something I'd like to avoid out of principle.

Therefore my question: does anyone have any good ideas on how to circumvent that issue and have a method (script?) that:

- decrypts the keys I use for dropbear (e.g. using `gnupg`) and loads them into memory,
- passes them to the `dbclient`-binary (the `dropbear`-client-application), and
- starts the ssh-connection

In addition I'd like to know if an alternative to the `ssh`-config option (especially the ones for `Host`) exists for dropbear (and therefore if it is possible to create a host-specific config file for dropbear where I can specify e.g. the IP-address, the port and other details).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that `dbclient` is entirely willing to read the private key from a named pipe or FIFO.

So with bash's process substitution, you can write:

```
dbclient -i <(cat .ssh/id_dropbear) user@server
```

So if you have a GPG encrypted `.ssh/id_dropbear.gpg`, you can write it as:

```
dbclient -i <(gpg --decrypt .ssh/id_dropbear.gpg) user@server
```

And after entering your decryption password, `dbclient` logs in using your GPG encrypted private key. So that part works fine.

The main issue here is that if you already stored `.ssh/id_dropbear` unencrypted before that, it could be recovered forensically. To encrypt a key on the fly from `dropbearconvert`, you can apply the same principle:

```
$ dropbearconvert openssh dropbear \
    .ssh/id_openssh >(gpg --symmetric --output .ssh/id_dropbear.gpg)
Key is a ssh-rsa key
Wrote key to '/dev/fd/63'
```

But it does not seem to be too useful in practice, since `dropbearconvert` also offers only very limited support for OpenSSH's encrypted private keys. For this example I had to specially create an OpenSSH key that `dropbearconvert` understands...

Unfortunately, this trick does not seem to work at all for the `dropbearkey` command, which for some reason insists on writing to a temporary file and renaming it, circumventing the pipe entirely.

Thus it appears you have no choice but to generate the private key in `tmpfs` first (like in `/dev/shm` or from a live cd), and encrypt it from there.

Comment: thanks for your answer, that works great! Just one thing: for process substitution it's necessary to `set +o posix` since otherwise this will result in the following error message: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('.

Comment: There is also a nice answer on the topic of [Sensitive data in process substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/381160/30851) so this approach can still be considered somewhat less secure than what openssh client does internally.